# how I can execute scripts on docker-machine create

Tags: docker, docker-machine

how can I run a command via docker machine? it's possible?
while automating the creation of servers I want to run the installation of some software on the hosts.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to map a volume from your docker container to your host and run the installation script in the shared volume with host so you get what you installed on the host.

Answer (score 5):

You can run custom commands on your machines using command `docker-machine ssh <machine name> <command>`.